# Convert Minutes to human readable format?

Tags: php, datetime, time

Is there a function in PHP to convert Minutes to human readable format?

For example, convert hour to minutes

```
$weekday = 2 //Tuesday
$OpenTime = "18:00"
$open = explode(':',$OpenTime);
$MinutesOpen = $weekday * ($open[0] * 60 + $open[1]);
echo $MinutesOpen;
```

`$MinutesOpen` will be 2160

How to convert it back to HH:MM format?

Comment: Have a look at PHP's DateTime class -- it will change your life.

Comment: Use the search function -- it will change your life as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

php has a date() function can do what you want.  or you can perform the calculation your self. `$str = sprintf('%02d:%02d', floor($min/60), $min%60)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$hoursminsandsecs = date('H:i:s',strtotime($MinutesOpen));
```